# Location of Hagemeister's six-language diaries

Tags: russia, naval, colonial-america, resource, research

Leontii A. Hagemeister (or Gagemeister) was a Baltic German navigator of the Russian navy and briefly governor of the Russian-American company. The best work on him in English is by Richard Pierce, whose *Builders of Alaska* repackages 1970s work saying that Hagemeister's journals remained unstudied: "One difficulty for the scholar is that he kept his diaries in Russian, German, English, Spanish, French and Portuguese." Pierce did not mention where the documents were kept, and I haven't succeeded in finding out. Which archive holds Hagemeister's diaries?

Comment: Your best bet to get an answer to this question would be to directly contact archives you think might have information on the documents in question. Some research I've done has turned up that there are documents written by Hagemeister at the archives at the National History Museum of Latvia, the [Perm oblast archive](http://www.archive.perm.ru/en/history), and the UAF 
Elmer E. Rasmuson Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the author, Glenn Farris, I obtained a copy of "Report on a Project to seek out documents describing early 19th Century California housed in the Russian Naval Archives in St. Petersburg, Russia". It contains a translation of a 2005 letter from the director of the Russian Naval Archive (RGAVMF), Vladimir Semenovich Sobolev, who describes the archive's holdings: "There are original journals kept during the voyages of V.M. Golovnin and L.A. Hagemeister.". I believe that the latter is the document in question.